# In psql some commands change prompt from =# to -# and do nothing

Tags: postgresql, psql

In my django project, I use postgresql to manage the database.
the pg version is 9.3

when I enter the psql terminal,some commands work,like `\d`, `\l`, `\h ,etc

When I type `CREATE TABLE.....`, `CREATE USER ....`, etc they are all negative and do nothing but change the prompt to `-#` from `=#`.

I just wonder if I missed something when installation so I reinstalled it - no change.

help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not finishing off your statement with a ; semicolon.